# Recover MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, recover

Accidently dropped my database from MySQL.

Is there any way to recover that table?

Comment: Yes. Use the backup that you made.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to recover most of the database from your backups (you did have some, didn't you?).

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html) has information for you on how to do so.